# Angular6 typescript extension method Observable<T>

Tags: typescript, angular6, extension-methods

I am trying to do an extension method on Observable

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

declare module 'rxjs/Observable' {
  interface Observable<T> {
    customFilter<T>(this: Observable<T>): Observable<T>;
  }
}

function customFilter<T>(this: Observable<T>) {
  return this;
}

Observable.prototype.customFilter = customFilter;
```

Howerver I am always getting a compilation error

```
ERROR in src/app/utils/observable.extensions.ts(13,1): error TS2693: 'Observable' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

Here's my tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "types": [],
    "paths": {
      "@angular/*": [
        "../node_modules/@angular/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: You are importing `Observable`, a type, and modifying it (implying it's a value). This cannot be done if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a subtle one.  The `rxjs/Observable` module contains:

```
export * from 'rxjs-compat/Observable';
```

Your augmentation of an exported interface named `Observable` is blocking the `export *` statement from re-exporting `Observable` from `rxjs-compat/Observable`, just as if `export interface Observable<T> { ... }` had been written directly in the `rxjs/Observable` module.  (Maybe the compiler should report an error when this happens.  There was [an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9532) open about this at one point, but it got closed without a clear statement about why the error couldn't be reported.)  As a consequence, the only definition of `Observable` exported from `rxjs/Observable` is the interface in your augmentation; no value meaning is available.

The fix is to change your augmentation to target `rxjs/internal/Observable` (where the `Observable` class is originally declared) instead of `rxjs/Observable`, so that your interface properly merges with the original class.